# Create an image with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, imagettftext

I need your help! My intention is to create a dynamic image with changing content, at the moment I am working with PHP and imagettftext, the User can access it via „banner.php“ and use it as image, because the header defines it as image.

But now I want to „upgrade“ the image editor where you change the values of the banner.php image (like the fontsize and the position) and I want a new „drag-and-drop“ editor for the user, where he can combine multiple images, texts and so on, but also dynamic values and at the end the editor should output it as „image“ (the user should be able to use it as img src).

What is the best way to create a drag-and-drop editor with image ouput?

Comment: Have you tried coding this?

Comment: I don‘t know how to starts, that‘s the thing

Answer (score 0):

Try MPDF library, 
You need to convert your image to  svg then you will get all the source of image where you can change every element of image dynamically , after change all the thing you want then convert it to image as well.

You just need to use MPDF library properly